# git ssh config no address associated with name

Tags: git, ssh, config

My ssh-settings:

C:\Users\maether.ssh\config

```
host maether
        user git
        hostname xx.xx.xx.xx
        identityfile ~/.ssh/maether/maether
        Port xxxxx
```

my RSA-Files are in folder: `c:\Users\maether\.ssh\maether\`

I open `cmd` and type in:

```
ssh maether
```

Normally i should get an answer of my git-repository, but i got:

> ssh: maether: no address associated with name"

If i typed in `echo %HOME%`, i got `C:\Users\maether\.ssh`

I take the same way on different Computer and it works, but now i get this failure: `no address associated with name`.
What could i have forget?

Comment: Formatting your question and especially code and program output properly makes the question easier to understand and improves the chance for a great answer a lot. Please check if the error message I copied from the title to the last paragraph is exactly the error message you got.

Answer (score 1):

It should be

```
c:\Users\maether\.ssh\config
```

not

```
c:\Users\maether.ssh\config
```

note the missing `\`.

Comment: sry, just a typing error here. The ssh-config-file of course is: c:\Users\maether.ssh\config

Comment: looks like you mistyped it again!

Comment: c:\ Users \ maether \ .ssh \ config

Comment: i think, stackoverflow has a buggy text-validator :)